# mouse events are not tregerd

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

the events in R3F are not being tregered for some reason, onPointerOver and OnPointerOut usually work fine but not here.

**I have a Plane compenent that return a mesh containt  a plane with the image as its material:**

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useRef,useState } from "react"
import { useFrame } from "react-three-fiber"
import lerp from "lerp"
import "./CustomMaterial"
import { useBlock } from "../blocks"
import state from "../store"

const Plane = forwardRef(({ color = "white", shift = 1, opacity = 1, args, map, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { viewportHeight, offsetFactor } = useBlock()
  const material = useRef()
  let last = state.top.current
  
  const [hover, setHover] = useState();
 
  useFrame(() => {
    const { pages, top } = state
  
    material.current.scale = lerp(material.current.scale, offsetFactor - top.current / ((pages - 1) * viewportHeight), 0.1)
    material.current.shift = lerp(material.current.shift, (top.current - last) / shift, 0.1)
    last = top.current
  })
  return (
    <mesh 
    onPointerOver={(e) => {
     
      console.log('over')
    }}
    onPointerOut={() => {
      
      console.log('out')
    }}
    
    ref={ref} {...props}>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={args} />
      <customMaterial ref={material} attach="material" color={color} map={map} transparent opacity={opacity} />
    </mesh>
  )
})

export default Plane
```

implemented inside this component:

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from "react"
import { Canvas, Dom, useLoader, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber"
import { TextureLoader, LinearFilter } from "three"
import lerp from "lerp"
import { Text, MultilineText } from "./components/Text"
import Diamonds from "./diamonds/Diamonds"
import Plane from "./components/Plane"
import Image from "./components/Image"
import { Block, useBlock } from "./blocks"
import state from "./store"
import "./styles.css"

function Startup() {
  const ref = useRef()
  useFrame(() => (ref.current.material.opacity = lerp(ref.current.material.opacity, 0, 0.025)))
  return <Plane ref={ref} color="#0e0e0f" position={[0, 0, 200]} scale={[100, 100, 1]} />
}

function Paragraph({ image, index, offset, factor, header, aspect, text }) {
  const { contentMaxWidth: w, canvasWidth, margin, mobile } = useBlock()
  const size = aspect < 1 && !mobile ? 0.65 : 1
  const alignRight = (canvasWidth - w * size - margin) / 2
  const pixelWidth = w * state.zoom * size
  const left = !(index % 2)
  const color = index % 2 ? "#D40749" : "#2FE8C3"
  return (
    <Block factor={factor} offset={offset}>
      <group position={[left ? -alignRight : alignRight, 0, 0]}>
        <Plane map={image} args={[1, 1, 32, 32]} shift={75} size={size} aspect={aspect} scale={[w * size, (w * size) / aspect, 1]} frustumCulled={false} />
        {/* <Dom
          style={{ width: pixelWidth / (mobile ? 1 : 2), textAlign: left ? "left" : "right" }}
          position={[left || mobile ? (-w * size) / 2 : 0, (-w * size) / 2 / aspect - 0.4, 1]}>
          <div tabIndex={index}>{text}</div>
        </Dom>
        <Text left={left} right={!left} size={w * 0.04} color={color} top position={[((left ? -w : w) * size) / 2, (w * size) / aspect / 2 + 0.5, -1]}>
          {header}
        </Text>
        <Block factor={0.2}>
          <Text opacity={0.5} size={w * 0.1} color="#1A1E2A" position={[((left ? w : -w) / 2) * size, (w * size) / aspect / 1.5, -10]}>
            {"0" + (index + 1)}
          </Text>
        </Block> */}
      </group>
    </Block>
  )
}

function Content() {
  const images = useLoader(
    TextureLoader,
    state.paragraphs.map(({ image }) => image)
  )
  useMemo(() => images.forEach(texture => (texture.minFilter = LinearFilter)), [images])
  const { contentMaxWidth: w, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mobile } = useBlock()
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Block factor={1} offset={0}>
        <Block factor={1.2}>
          <Text left size={w * 0.08} position={[-w / 3.2, 0.5, -1]} color="#d40749">
            MOKSHA
          </Text>
        </Block>
        <Block factor={1.0}>
          <Dom position={[-w / 3.2, -w * 0.08 + 0.25, -1]}>It was the year 2076.{mobile ? <br /> : " "}The substance had arrived.</Dom>
        </Block>
      </Block>
      <Block factor={1.2} offset={5.7}>
        <MultilineText top left size={w * 0.15} lineHeight={w / 5} position={[-w / 3.5, 0, -1]} color="#2fe8c3" text={"four\nzero\nzero"} />
      </Block> */}
      {state.paragraphs.map((props, index) => (
        <Paragraph key={index} index={index} {...props} image={images[index]} />
      ))}
      {/* {state.stripes.map(({ offset, color, height }, index) => (
        <Block key={index} factor={-1.5} offset={offset}>
          <Plane args={[50, height, 32, 32]} shift={-4} color={color} rotation={[0, 0, Math.PI / 8]} position={[0, 0, -10]} />
        </Block>
      ))}
      <Block factor={1.25} offset={8}>
        <Dom className="bottom-left" position={[-canvasWidth / 2, -canvasHeight / 2, 0]}>
          Culture is not your friend.
        </Dom>
      </Block> */}
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  const scrollArea = useRef()
  const onScroll = e => (state.top.current = e.target.scrollTop)
  useEffect(() => void onScroll({ target: scrollArea.current }), [])
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas className="canvas" concurrent pixelRatio={1} orthographic camera={{ zoom: state.zoom, position: [0, 0, 500] }}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Dom center className="loading" children="Loading..." />}>
          <Content />
          {/* <Diamonds />
          <Startup /> */}
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      <div className="scrollArea" ref={scrollArea} onScroll={onScroll}>
        {new Array(state.sections).fill().map((_, index) => (
          <div key={index} id={"0" + index} style={{ height: `${(state.pages / state.sections) * 100}vh` }} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="frame">
        <h1 className="frame__title">Scroll, Refraction and Shader Effects</h1>
        <div className="frame__links">
          <a className="frame__link" href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PhysicsMenu/">
            Previous demo
          </a>
          <a className="frame__link" href="https://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=45441">
            Article
          </a>
          <a className="frame__link" href="https://github.com/drcmda/the-substance">
            GitHub
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="frame__nav">
          <a className="frame__link" href="#00" children="intro" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#01" children="01" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#02" children="02" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#03" children="03" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#04" children="04" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#05" children="05" />
          <a className="frame__link" href="#07" children="06" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

the whole thing is an adaptation of this example of r3f:
[Moksha](https://codesandbox.io/s/moksha-f1ixt)

Comment: What seems to be the problem to me is that you set a state before the console.log so a new render of the react dom happens before the console.log happens, try to invert setHover(false);
      console.log('out')

Comment: thanks for the commnet. but that did not change anything.